# Rename vmware snapshot

Tags: c#-4.0, vmware

I have windows desktop application which commands or automates VMware functionalities. I want to rename existing snapshot and update same with following flow, but i don't see any vmware API to rename existing snapshot. Can anyone provide me info on how to rename vmware snapshot? 
Thanks

> Click on ‘Register and initiate snapshot’-> Initiate Guest VM
>   Shutdown->Rename Current Snapshot- SS1 to Temp-SS1->Take New Snapshot
>   with current snapshot name(i.e. SS1)->delete previous renamed
>   snapshot(i.e. Temp-SS1).

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: VirtualMachine vmObject = (VirtualMachine) vimClient.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, filter, null).FirstOrDefault();
                if (vmObject != null)
                {
                    vmObject.ShutdownGuest();
     "Here i want to rename my previous snapshot(SS! to 'Temp SS1')"
     vmObject.CreateSnapshot(snapShotName, snapShotDescription, false, false);

                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above can be done by simple following two methods:

```
public bool CreateSnapShot(string vmName, string snapShotName, string snapShotDescription, bool replaceSnapShot, string currentSnapShotName)
    {
        try
        {
            NameValueCollection filter = new NameValueCollection();
            filter.Add(Constants.VM_FILTER_NAME, vmName);

            ManagedObjectReference snapShotMor = null;
            VirtualMachine vmObject = (VirtualMachine) vimClient.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, filter, null).FirstOrDefault();
            if (vmObject != null)
            {
                if (vmObject.Runtime.PowerState == VirtualMachinePowerState.poweredOn)
                    vmObject.ShutdownGuest();
                while (vmObject.Runtime.PowerState == VirtualMachinePowerState.poweredOn)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    vmObject.UpdateViewData();//This will refresh VM object state
                }

                if (replaceSnapShot && currentSnapShotName!= "")
                {
                    if (RenameSnapshot(snapShotName, vmObject))
                        snapShotMor = vmObject.CreateSnapshot(snapShotName, snapShotDescription, false, false);
                }
                else snapShotMor = vmObject.CreateSnapshot(snapShotName, snapShotDescription, false, false);

                if (snapShotMor != null)
                    return true;
                else return false;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }           
    }
```

Snapshot rename can be done by following method:

```
public bool RenameSnapshot(string snapShotName, VirtualMachine vmObject)
    {
        try
        {                                                 
             ManagedObjectReference snapshotObject = vmObject.Snapshot.CurrentSnapshot;
             VirtualMachineSnapshot currentSnapshotName = new VirtualMachineSnapshot(vimClient, snapshotObject);
             currentSnapshotName.RenameSnapshot("Temp-" + snapShotName, "Renamed for deletion");

            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

After above two steps you can delete renamed(Temp) snapshot.